# what pattern/framework should i use for my program?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, frameworks

My program should run like a simulator for cars.
I have plenty of car models and each car model has its own set of properties.
Properties of these cars may be the same and may vary. For example, one car can have 3 properties while another car can have the same 4 properties in which 3 is the same with the first car. And also, case can be that two cars can have the same property name but in different data type.
There is also the possibility of adding another model and/or property.
What pattern or framework should i use for my program. Help me out geeks!

Comment: You may be better off asking this question over at the [programmers site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It sounds like your question is about basic OOP, not patterns or frameworks.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky can you just help me with an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what the essential properties of your cars are, and put them in an abstract base class (or an interface, but base class is more appropriate). You can make a deeper hierarchy if some properties are on one class of cars, and others on another. (Get it, classes?) You can use interfaces if these classes of properties overlap and you need multiple inheritance.

What different types does one of your properties have? If these are user types, give them a common base class. Otherwise give the properties different names. In any case, this sounds like a code smell

Not every property should be in a base class. Use inheritance only where appropriate. But also reexamine which properties you think you need and rationalize them. I'm sure you've made bad choices somewhere, but you gave no examples of your properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory pattern

There will be a ICar interface.

And all car models will be the concrete classes.Write all contract in the ICar interface.

In the concrete class implement only the necessary  properties.

Comment: how about the varying of data types on a property?

Comment: Thats not what the factory pattern is. This is called inheritance.